# How to handle correctly converting images to thumbnails

Tags: thumbnails

I'm building out an admin area for an ecommerce site where the user can create a new product and upload multiple images to be used for the product. I have a table that lists all of the products, each row shows the first image returned from the database. I can scale down a large image to 100px x 100px but the user is still downloading a big image, not a true thumbnail.

I see two ways of doing this: 
1. I can make the user choose which img will be the thumbnail so that the regular img is upload and also a smaller version of the file.

2.I can create thumbnails for every img that is uploaded and append to the filename of the thumbnail img so that I can return the first image that ends with a certain string.

Is there a more elegant way to do this or am I on the right track?

Comment: You didn't specify any technologies in either your question or the tags.

Comment: (Option 2 is the normal way to go about it.)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, Sorry, I felt the question did not pertain to any specific technology, but i'm using ASP.NET, C#, LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cache directory, then create a script called something like image.php. Link your images like this

```
<img src="image.php?path=images/img.png&width=100&height=100">
```

Then in image.php, it should first check in the cache directory if the file exists.
Call the file `"img.png&width=100&height=100"` and save it in the cache directory. That way you can easily check if it exists, but there is enough entropy for someone to change it to `width=101` and `height = 101` so that the image will be regenerated.

Each time you create the thumbnail, just store it in the cache directory. If it exists, do a `header()` call and an `echo file_get_contents()` and then `die()`.